# How to alphabetically sort all the records in a file in python from the 2nd column

Tags: python

So I have a file (sample:)

```
ID         Name       Course  Absences  Exam1 Grade Exam2 Grade Total Marks
202010000  Asem       ICS104      0         100         100         200
202010000  Asem       ICS108      2          75          -1          75
202010001  Khalid     ICS202      0          -1          -1          -1
201928690  Hamza      ICS104      0          80          -1          80
201928440  Abdullah   ICS104      0         100         100         200
```

I need to display all the records in this file in alphabetical order of the names (2nd column).
If I do this:

```
studentFile = open(input("Enter file name: "), "r")
lines = studentFile.readlines()
    for line in sorted(lines):
        print(line)
```

It sorts the file according to the 1st column (the ID numbers). How do I sort it using the 2nd column?

Comment: Write a function that extracts the second column from a line and pass that as the `key=` parameter to the [`sorted` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), like this: `sorted(lines, key=lambda l: l.split()[1])`

Comment: Break the lines up into arrays of values and then sort(key=lambda x: x[1])

Comment: @Boris if you make that `[1:]` instead of `[1]` you can use the following columns as part of the sort too.

Comment: @Boris thanks, it works.

Comment: @MarkRansom thanks for the tip